# How to access a shared S3 bucket (shared through ACL) from the grantee's account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl

Under the "Access Control List" in the "Permissions" tab of my S3 Console, I have added another AWS account to the "access for other AWS accounts" list for a specific bucket. However, after updating the ACL settings, that account is unable to view the bucket in their console. How can the grantee access the shared bucket in their web console?

I have pored over the S3 documentation but find it extremely confusing as a new user. I am simply trying to use the web console to access a shared bucket but haven't found documentation to help me do that.

Thank you!

Comment: Configuring other accounts in S3 bucket ACLs means that the resources from that account like EC2s, lambdas etc (which are allowed to access S3 service) can access the shared bucket. The S3 console doesn’t show the shared buckets.

Comment: @SukenShah then what is the best way to share a bucket so that many users can access it in their own S3 console?

Comment: A bucket from another account will not show in the S3 console. I can't think of any resource in AWS that does.

Answer (score 4):

The shared bucket won't show up in the grantee's bucket list, but they can still access it through the console by navigating directly to its URL: https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/shared-bucket-name.